Tesselating nets of hypercubes
A net of hypercubes is a unique unfolding of a higher-dimension hypercube. A n-cube can unfold into many distinct nets consisting of $2n$ (n-1)-cubes. There are 11 unique unfoldings of a cube into 2D nets, 261 for 4-cubes, and so on. I recently learned about all of this through Matt Parker's video on it and became interested in the idea of tesselating higher dimensions of space.
The Whuts Project showed that each of the 261 3D nets can tesselate space, so it seems like each 4D net from unfolding a 5-cube would tesselate 4D space. Is this concept even a real thing? As far as tesselation goes, is there some mathematical way to represent the methods of tesselating a shape in terms of vectors? For example, defining such a pattern of tesselation by a set of position vectors and rotation vectors and a distance in each dimension for which that set can repeat? I'd assume that trying to tesselate space in more than 3 dimensions visually will be futile, so surely there is a more numerical approach.
